# My professor submitted the draft recommendation letter with university name as placeholder. Can i re-submit?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

My professor accidentally sent the draft version of the recommendation letter to UTD and it had a mistake of the university name as "[Enter university name]" which was supposed to be replaced with the intended university name. It was submitted into a portal. Is there any way to remedy this? I've already submitted the application and emailed them about the mishap. What are my chances to remedy this situation?

Comment: I am not sure what's the problem here. Can't your professor resend the letter?

Comment: It's an online portal where you drop your submission and the portal is closed after you submit.

Comment: Most likely this will have no impact on the decision.

Comment: **You** can't do anything. In principle, the professor can resend the letter, either by revisiting the portal or by emailing the admissions committee directly, but it's really not worth the trouble.

Comment: How do you know what was in the letter the professor submitted?

Comment: He realized it after sending. I was shown the draft letter beforehand and he used a university placeholder for changing each time he would send the letter to any university. I've emailed the admission adviser and awaiting their reply

Answer (score 6):

Chill.

Admission committees get this sort of thing frequently.  We understand your professor's situation (because we write lots of recommendation letters ourselves).  It is very unlikely that a committee would even bother to comment...

... and a tiny mistake on your professor's part certainly shouldn't affect your chances of admittance.

Comment: Are you a professor/teacher?

Comment: Yes, I am a professor.